# SELECT WHERE works but not when adding AND

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

So I have a bit of an issue with using my MySQL query string. I have a table with photo_id-s and I
would like to retrieve the image name of the highest photo_id of a given user_id. If I'm trying to get just the highest
photo_id, e.g.

```
SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE photo_id=(SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name);
```

Then all works dandy. However, soon as I add the AND for the WHERE statement, I receive a Resource #3
from the query's result. Query with AND:

```
SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE photo_id=(SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name) AND user_id=1;
```

This seems such a simple task yet I've been stumped for longer than I'd like on this one. All
help appreciated.
The php code as a whole (the important bit at least)

```
<?php

  include('includes/connection.php');

  // this one works fine
  $photoQuery = "SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE photo_id=(SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name)";
  // Buggy query
  // $photoQuery = "SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE photo_id=(SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name) AND user_id=5"; 

  $result = mysql_query($photoQuery);
  if(!$result){
    die(mysql_error());
  }

  var_dump($result);
  $latestPhoto = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

  var_dump($latestPhoto);
  echo "lastPhoto - " . $latestPhoto . "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank you. I've just recently been learning MySQLi but this is an old project I'm tinkering on and won't find any actual use anywhere, hence I'm not that worried about security caveats. mysql_ or not, if you could, why would my code not be working?

Comment: Just for fun, try `SELECT 
        image 
        (SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name) AS max_img 
  
    FROM 
        table_name

    WHERE 
        user_id=1`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That throws an error

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM ajv123654_photos) AS max_img FROM ajv123654_photos WHE' at line 1 `

Comment: Hm, that is Bizarre.

Comment: Forgot a comma, here try `SELECT 
        image, 
        (SELECT MAX(photo_id) FROM table_name) AS max_img 
  
    FROM 
        table_name

    WHERE 
        user_id=1`

Comment: Works as well now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the max value of `photo_id` the same id for all the users? I guess you may want something like:

```
SELECT image FROM table_name WHERE user_id=5 ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Please while giving a -1 give also an explanation/comment in order to improve/edit my answer

Comment: I can't vote up because of my low reputation, but this does the trick for me so will accept it in 4 minutes mate. Thank you, Charles!

Comment: @Kano That's ok, no problem... the goal is to give a solution